# open office document conversion uses 100% CPU

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, conversion, openoffice

When I try to convert a word document using the ooextract python script from open office like

```
/usr/local/bin/ooextract.py myDocument.doc myDocument.pdf
```

the open office deamon (sOffice.bin) takes 100% CPU load forever.

We are using Open Office 2.6.3 on a virtual machine running debian squeeze 2.6.32-5-amd64

UPDATE:

We found out that this appears only with our test document, other documents can be converted without problem. But how can we find out what's wrong with our document. How can we enable traces/loggin o the sOffice.bin process?

Comment: You may want to include file size, etc. And does the conversion ever complete? Sounds like there could be a bug in the script.

Comment: Using 100% of your CPU is the best thing a program can do. The faster it runs, the more early it will finish. Your problem is, that it takes so long to run, the absolute CPU occupation, not the relative one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem to be related to Open Office Version 2.6.3, with Open Office 3.3.0 we do not have the problem anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. To debug it, I put the test document under version control and removed significant chunks of it at a time; ensuring I took note of what structures were removed.

This let me isolate it to an issue with 2.4.1 and a Table, containing a Row, with lots of text content. The table was allowed to split across pages, the row was not. Rendering to PDF caused  a similar 100% CPU usage issue.